# Unable to integrate Google Calender API in yii

Tags: php, yii, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to integrate Google Calender API with my yii app.

I followed [this link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/setup) steps for PHP:

- I added the google library folder as a component
- included the path for library `src` folder in `config/main.php`
- added the `autoload.php` file using `require_once`.

When I try to run it, I am getting an error

> include(Google_Client.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Isn't `autoload.php` file supposed to include all the files required from google library? But somehow it's not happening. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It was the problem with autoload. I unregistered yii's autoload then called the libraries autoload, then re-registered yii autoload. It worked.

I added these lines to fix it:

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
require_once realpath('/path/to/google/autoload.php');
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```